# How can I set a var value to my current latitude or longitude? Updated code provided by nikhil

Tags: swift

I need to access these coordinate values outside of the class in order to compute certain equations, however when I try to assign myLat to UserCoordinates.userLat or UserCoordinates.userLong an error occurs.

I've tried using both structs and classes as well as global variables however all returned various errors.

```
    public class UserCoordinates {
        static let  shared:UserCoordinates = UserCoordinates()
        var userLat: Double?
        var userLong: Double?

        func setUserLat(userLat: Double, userLong: Double) {
            self.userLong = userLong
            self.userLat = userLat
        }
        private init() {

        }
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
            guard let location = locations.last else {
                return
            }
            userLat = Double(location.coordinate.latitude)
            userLong = Double(location.coordinate.longitude)
        }

    }

sin(my latitude)
I want to take the sin of my latitude wherever I am how would I assign the value of userLat in the class/function to this sin calculation?
```

Comment: `userLat ` is an instance variable not class, you have to create an instance first.

Comment: How would I do that? I've tried var myLat = UserCoordinates() but it returned Instance member 'userLat' cannot be used on type 'UserCoordinates'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access a variable using a class unless it's static. If you want something that to be one instance then you should use singleton check this below code.

```
public class UserCoordinates {
    static let  shared:UserCoordinates = UserCoordinates()
    var userLat: Double?
    var userLong: Double?

    func setUserLat(userLat: Double, userLong: Double) {
        self.userLong = userLong
        self.userLat = userLat
    }
    private init() {

    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        userLat = Double(location.coordinate.latitude)
        userLong = Double(location.coordinate.longitude)
    }

}
UserCoordinates.shared.setUserLat(userLat: 10.0, userLong: 10.0)
let myLat = UserCoordinates.shared.userLat
```

Comment: However, all this does is set myLat to ten obviously. I can't figure out how to set myLat to UserCoordinates.shared.userLat which I assume would give the user's current location